# Select Between Two Dates column data with times

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server

Date time is in my column

```
2019-04-30 20:56:18.237

I need to select Between Two Dates
```

I am tired from this

```
WHERE  DateTime BETWEEN '2019-04-5 00:00' and '2019-04-30 12:00'
```

is there any solution please?

Sql 2012/
VisualStudio 2013

Comment: Your current approach is probably the best approach.  Why are you tired of it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think **Tried**

Comment: @RiggsFolly My brain is **fried** from trying to compete with Gordon.  It didn't go well for me :P

Comment: Should that be `BETWEEN '2019-04-05 00:00' and '2019-04-30 23:59:59'` to include the date you mention above

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen did you mean `Fired` :) Dont compete, **Augment** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally get your issue.  This `WHERE` clause is correctly formed:

```
WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2019-04-5 00:00' and '2019-04-30 12:00'
```

However, `'2019-04-30 20:56:18.237'` is not between these values.  If you want to express the idea of *any* date/time in April on or after the fifth, then I recommend:

```
WHERE DateTime >= '2019-04-05' AND
      DateTime < '2019-05-01'
```

I strongly discourage you from using `BETWEEN` with date/time values.  Aaron Bertrand explains this very well in his blog 
[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)